# Pass data out of directive

Tags: angularjs

I built a custom directive which presents some options to the user similar to a dropdown (let's suppose that a "real" `<select>` element wasn't appropriate for this particular case).

The directive is fed data and displays it.
It also attaches a click listener for each item.
Items are identified by a unique number.

How should the directive communicate outside its scope what the clicked item's number is?

Thanks.

Comment: question is far too vague without code context.

Comment: I disagree, if you read it carefully you'll see that it's not vague and that it doesn't require code to be shown.

Comment: sure... you disagree because you know how the app works. Yes it's vague and code is part of SO question guidelines

Comment: It's not about an app or code. It's about a concept. If I ask you how a leaf falls, do you need me to draw a tree?

Comment: Also, I don't care much about guidelines in general.

Answer (score 8):

You should use two-way data binding to pass values out of a directive into it's parent. Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/D85A2/1.

```
<div my-directive id="selectedId">
<p>The selected item is {{selectedId}}</p>

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            id: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.setItem = function (id) {
                scope.id = id;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Eddie. Wouldn't a better solution be using an `&` expression? The difference would be having a method on the controller called when selection changes vs. a `$watch` on a scope property.

Comment: it depends what you're trying to achieve, use `=` to pass a value directly back to the parent. Use `&` if you want to evaluate an expression on the parent (like an update question ID method that performs some logic). In the case of your question where you simply want a question ID using `=` sounds the most sensible.

Comment: I gave it more thought and `&` is the best option when you just want inform a parent controller of a change. this is because (1) `$watch` costs while calling an expression exactly when you need it does not and (2) because the directive is dirtying the scope of the controller and if you were to have multiple directives, they would all battle for the same scope property name.

Answer (score 2):

All depends what you want to do with this clicked number, but generally, this is where Angular's services come in handy. Create a service, inject said service into your directive, set the clicked number in that service, inject where you need it and use it.

Sample service:

```
myApp.factory("myFactory", function() {
    this.clicked = 0;
    return {
        get: function() {
            return this.clicked;
        },
        set: function(num) {
            this.clicked = num;
        }
    }
});
```

Now you can run `myFactory.set(num)` -- and retrieve with `myFactory.get();`

Comment: It depends on the context. Services could be the solution here, or two-way data binding.

Comment: @eddiec -- Yup, agreed - just thought I'd throw it out there. The service concept of Angular is hard to grasp sometimes, but once you get used to it, gotta love it!

Comment: Agree with both the answers here I see the third option of communication (though I haven't really used it in practice) is to use $emit $broadcast and $on to use events to "pass" the information around or let it be sent out and captured.

Comment: I want the controller to react immediately. Using a service with setters and getters will just store state that is already stored in the directive. Thanks for the suggestion though.